# How to fix the error while running cro function in R?

Tags: r

```
df1<-read_excel('exam.xlsx')
names(df1)

[1] "HAART_reg"    "Base_CD4"     "CD4_at_12"    "diabetes"    
[5] "hypertension" "tuberculosis" "Base"         "CD412"
```

I want to make a cross table using the variables `Base` and `CD412` which are categorical variables with levels `0` and `1`

`library(expss)`

`cro(df1$Base,df1$CD412)`

The following error message appears:

`Error in name_dots(...) : could not find function "name_dots"`

How to fix this?

Comment: Try to reinstall both data.table and expss: `install.packages(c("data.table", "expss"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about trying `devtools::install_github("gdemin/expss")`?

Or the second option is to run:

```
name_dots <- function(...) {
dot_sub <- as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1L]
vnames = names(dot_sub)
if (is.null(vnames)) {
vnames = rep.int("", length(dot_sub))
novname = rep.int(TRUE, length(dot_sub))
} else {
vnames[is.na(vnames)] = ""
if (any(vnames==".SD")) stop("A column may not be called .SD. That has special meaning.")
novname = vnames==""
}
for (i in which(novname)) {
if ((tmp <- deparse(dot_sub[[i]])[1L]) == make.names(tmp))
vnames[i] = tmp
}
still_empty = vnames==""
if (any(still_empty)) vnames[still_empty] = paste0("V", which(still_empty))
list(vnames=vnames, novname=novname)
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/R/utils.R